# Can't move Chrysler 300M gear selector out of park

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, shifting

I got into my car this morning and couldn't move it from park after I started it. I can't change the gear at all. I can move the wheel, though. I've tried to wiggle it but haven't forced it because I don't wanna cause any damage.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What car is it?

Comment: Chrysler 300M 1999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My wife had a similar problem with her Outback at one point.  There is a shift lock preventing the level from moving out of park when you press the brake.

First, check to see if you can just unlock the shift lock mechanism.  There's an excellent set of illustrations here:

http://www.lxforums.com/board/f90/cant-shift-out-park-into-gear-pink-thingy-replacement-234335/

[image: Try pushing this button to get out of park.]

Note, that site also recommends a replacement part for the problem.  It apparently works wonders for some people.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

There's a solenoid that needs to be activated to allow you to shift from park. Generally this solenoid is only energized when you depress the brake pedal (there may be other requirements as well).

When you step on the brake pedal, do the brake lights go on? If not, you've likely got a faulty brake switch.

If the brake lights work, then it could be the shift lock solenoid itself that has gone bad, or is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Chrysler 300, dismantle plastic pieces around shifter, you need Phillips two scews forward top under thin cover, take whole thing out, now you see side of gear selector mount, toward u you see cable behind that "pink thing" get screw driver behehind that nudge forward, E break on!..with other hand get her out of park while nudgeing pink thing forward, that is a lock and it is useless anymore, peace:-)

Comment: Right hand,side of shifter, forward there's cable connect, behind that is pink thing

Answer (score 0):

Same thing just happened to my wife's 2005 Chrysler 300 LTD. Search a "K39 Recall". Chrysler should fix for free!! (Aug. 2015)

Comment: The [K39 recall](http://onlineautotech.com/articles/dodgechrysler-floor-shifter-recall/) does not apply to this person's car, as the recall affects 2005-2007 Chrysler Charger, Challenger, and 300M. While the recall does not apply, the fix may help the OP.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me great. Easy to follow.

Part One

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I49uU65HMmM

Part Two

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzHiuWpYb0M